# Get the value from xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml like prd.xml

```
  <product>
<text>Some Text</text>
    <name>Pname</name>
    <category extra="category"> Test</category>
    </product>
```

I want to get the category from the xml using xslt.

I tried like

```
<xsl:variable name="p" select="prd.xml"/>

<xsl:value-of select ="$p/product/category"/>
```

but I can't get the result.Anybody help any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
 select="prd.xml"
```

selects an element `prd.xml` which isn't there, you want

```
select="document('prd.xml')"
```